# how to write the single aggregation in the query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregate-functions

I am writing the first query greater than equal to CREATE_DATE and less then CREATE_DATE I got the answer ofter calculate the duration write another query but how to write the single query in the aggregation.

> Query 1

```
db.lights.aggregate({
  $match: {
    CREATE_DATE: {
      $gte: ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"),
      $lt: ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30.000Z")
    }
  }
});
```

**Result**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a9a74843711955836a8b4b5"),
  "SWITCHID": "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
  "CREATE_DATE": ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30Z"),
  "RECEIVEDDATE": ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:45Z"),
  "STATUS": "LIGHTS ON"
}
```

> Query 2

```
db.lights.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      offduration: {
        $divide: [
          {
            $subtract: [
              "$RECEIVEDDATE",
              "$CREATE_DATE"
            ]
          },
          3600000
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Result**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5a9a75af3711955836a8b4c8"),
  "SWITCHID": "Z4-W40-SS451A/5",
  "CREATE_DATE": ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30Z"),
  "RECEIVEDDATE": ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:45Z"),
  "STATUS": "LIGHTS ON",
  "offduration": 0.004166666666666667
}
```

Comment: You cant combine the two queries as they produce different data. If you combine them you will get no results.Please adjust your data range and use `db.lights.aggregate([{ $match: { CREATE_DATE : {$gte: ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"), $lte: ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30.000Z")} }},{$addFields: { duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]} }}])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to improve your query like this :

```
db.lights.aggregate({
  $match: {
  CREATE_DATE: {
    $gte: ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"),
    $lt: ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30.000Z")
    }
  }
},
 {
  $addFields: {
    offduration: {
      $divide: [
        {
          $subtract: [
            "$RECEIVEDDATE",
            "$CREATE_DATE"
          ]
        },
        3600000
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
$project: {
  _id: 1,
  SWITCHID: 1,
  CREATE_DATE: 1,
  RECEIVEDDATE: 1,
  STATUS: 1,
  offduration: '$offduration',
  avgduration: { $avg: "$offduration" }      
 }
});
```

Comment: perfect....i got the out put is
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a9a74843711955836a8b4b5"),
 "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
 "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30Z"),
 "RECEIVEDDATE" : ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:45Z"),
 "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON",
 "offduration" : 744.0041666666667
}
i have one question  Z4-W40-SS451A/4  same SWITCHID number of there how to calculate avarage offduration  please  help me sir...

Comment: You need to look in `$avg` in mongodb documentation

Comment: @  Neel Rathod iam using $ avg but not get all fields 
output:
{
 "_id" : {
  "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/10",
  "STATUS" : "LIGHTS OFF"
 },
 "avgduration" : 0.03333333333333333
}
{
 "_id" : {
  "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/5",
  "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON"
 },
 "avgduration" : 202.50562416666668
}

Comment: @ Neel Rathod i am add this aggregation in this previous aggregation 
{"$group" : {     _id: {         SWITCHID: "$SWITCHID",            STATUS: "$STATUS"     },     avgduration: { $avg: "$offduration" } }}